# monotouch 'mtouch failed with no output (1)'

Tags: xamarin.ios

I updated my monotouch yesterday to the latest version and updated Xcode to 3.2.5 with the iOS sdk to support iOS SDK 4.2 (to support an ipod touch with 4.2.1).

I am now having problems upon compiling for the device, 'mtouch failed with no output (1)'. 
My solution does NOT have any spaces in either the folders or the project name.

I have updated SDKs in the past, and have used the advice for the 'Base SDK Missing' issue successfully.

All of the online advice about  'mtouch failed with no output (1)' deals with spaces in the project/folder names. I have even tried creating a new trivial project with monotouch, and still have this problem.

Any ideas?

```
Building: TestNewVersion (Release|iPhone)

Building Solution TestNewVersion

Building: TestNewVersion (Release|iPhone)

Detecting signing identity...
Provisioning profile: "Team Provisioning Profile: *" (XXXXXX)
Signing Identity: "iPhone Developer: MyName (XXXXXX)"
App ID: "XXXX.testnewversion"

Performing main compilation...

Updating CodeBehind files
Updated MainWindow.xib.designer.cs
Updated RootViewController.xib.designer.cs
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/smcs /noconfig "/out:/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.exe" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" /nologo /warn:4 /optimize- /codepage:utf8 /t:exe "/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/Main.cs" "/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/MainWindow.xib.designer.cs" "/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/RootViewController.xib.cs" "/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/RootViewController.xib.designer.cs" 
Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)

/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/RootViewController.xib.cs(75,44): warning CS0414: The private field `TestNewVersion.RootViewController.DataSource.controller' is assigned but its value is never used


Build complete -- 0 errors, 1 warning

Compiling to native code
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch  -v --nomanifest --nosign -dev "/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.app"  -r="/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" -r="/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" -r="/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" -r="/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" -nolink -sdk="4.2" "/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.exe"
Framework is: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk
Copied /Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.exe to /Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.app/TestNewVersion.exe
MONO_PATH=/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,outfile=/var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/TestNewVersion.exe.s "/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.app/TestNewVersion.exe"
MONO_PATH=/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,outfile=/var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/mscorlib.dll.s "/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.app/mscorlib.dll"
MONO_PATH=/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,outfile=/var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/monotouch.dll.s "/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.app/monotouch.dll"
MONO_PATH=/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,outfile=/var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/System.dll.s "/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.app/System.dll"
MONO_PATH=/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,outfile=/var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.s "/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.app/Mono.Security.dll"
MONO_PATH=/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,outfile=/var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/System.Core.dll.s "/Users/MyName/Projects/TestNewVersion/TestNewVersion/bin/iPhone/Release/TestNewVersion.app/System.Core.dll"
Generated /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/main.m
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.0 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -c /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/TestNewVersion.exe.s -o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/TestNewVersion.exe.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.0 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -c /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/mscorlib.dll.s -o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/mscorlib.dll.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.0 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -c /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/monotouch.dll.s -o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/monotouch.dll.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.0 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -c /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/System.dll.s -o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/System.dll.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.0 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -c /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.s -o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.0 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -c /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/System.Core.dll.s -o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/System.Core.dll.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.0 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -c /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/main.m -o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/main.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.0 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/TestNewVersion.exe.o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/mscorlib.dll.o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/monotouch.dll.o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/System.dll.o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/System.Core.dll.o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/registrar.m -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/main.o -o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/TestNewVersion -framework CFNetwork -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreTelephony -framework EventKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreMotion -framework GameKit -framework MapKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework OpenGLES -framework StoreKit -framework UIKit -framework AddressBookUI -framework iAd -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AddressBook -framework AudioToolbox -framework AudioUnit -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework ImageIO -framework Security -framework CoreMedia -framework ExternalAccessory -framework EventKitUI -framework QuickLook -lz -u _catch_exception_raise -u _CreateZStream -u _CloseZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -liconv -lmono -lmonotouch -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib -dead_strip
Process exited with code 1, command:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.0 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/TestNewVersion.exe.o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/mscorlib.dll.o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/monotouch.dll.o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/System.dll.o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/System.Core.dll.o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/registrar.m -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/main.o -o /var/folders/8P/8PRYWK7LE1yLdY8raiuKPU+++TM/-Tmp-/tmp44336f07.tmp/TestNewVersion -framework CFNetwork -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreTelephony -framework EventKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreMotion -framework GameKit -framework MapKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework OpenGLES -framework StoreKit -framework UIKit -framework AddressBookUI -framework iAd -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AddressBook -framework AudioToolbox -framework AudioUnit -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework ImageIO -framework Security -framework CoreMedia -framework ExternalAccessory -framework EventKitUI -framework QuickLook -lz -u _catch_exception_raise -u _CreateZStream -u _CloseZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -liconv -lmono -lmonotouch -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib -dead_strip

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build: 1 error, 2 warnings
```

Comment: Set the "Extra Arguments" to "-v -v -v" and post the complete build output.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click your project and choose "Options".  Under "Build" there is an option called "iPhone Build".  Under "SDK Version" make sure you pick a selection that you have installed.

For example, when I upgraded to 4.2, 3.2 was not installed.  If I download a sample project from Github that targets 3.2, it won't build until I fix that option.

Comment: Hi,I had already verified that the 'SDK Version' was set to 4.2. (The choices are 'Default' and 4.2. I have tried both.) I am only able to build for the simulator, not for the device.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a problem related to 
http://forums.monotouch.net/yaf_postst1323.aspx

The latest version of Monotouch 3.2.2 seems to have a problem with the 
**gcc_flags -framework AudioUnit**
that causes the error
**ld: framework not found AudioUnit**

The solution that was posted has the link option set to turn the linker on, compile, and then turn the linker off again and compile again.
This worked for a trivial project, but does not work for my much more complex project. I have had to revert to Monotouch 3.1.3 for now. Hopefully this will be fixed in the next version.
Thanks for your help!